# Using ModelBuilder to define an optional, one-to-many, self-referencing relationship?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have an entity, Post:

```
 public class Post
 {
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int PostId { get; set; }
 }
```

I have another entity, `Response`:

```
 public class Response
 {
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int ResponseId{ get; set; }

    public int PostId {get; set;}
    public int ParentResponseId {get; set;}
 }
```

The idea is, a `Response` either has a `ParentResponseId` defined, OR a `PostId` - but never both.  A `Post` can have many Responses, and a `Response` can have many Responses.

I never need to navigate from one to the other via `virtual` properties, nor do I need lazy loading - I just need the constraints set up in the db.

I'm new to modelBuilder but this seems like a case where it would have to be used.  I have a starting point:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Response>()
        .HasOptional(c => c.Post)
        .HasForeignKey(u => u.PostId);
  modelBuilder.Entity<Response>()
        .HasOptional(c => c.Response)
        .HasForeignKey(u => u.ParentResponseId);
```

Is this the correct way to handle an optional one-to-many?  Is there any way to add a constraint that says "one or the other FK needs to be defined"?  Any guidance here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have 4 classes now

```
public class Post
{
  [Key]
  [Required]
  public int PostId { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<PostResponse> Responses { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Response //abstract to never get just a simple response
{
  [Key]
  [Required]
  public int ResponseId{ get; set; }

  public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class PostResponse : Response
{
  [Required]
  public int PostId { get; set; }

  public Post Post { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseReply : Response
{
  [Required]
  public int ParentResponseId { get; set; }

  public virtual Response ParentResponse { get; set; }
}
```

In your ModelBuilder block:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PostResponse>()
            .ToTable("PostResponse")
            .HasRequired(c => c.Post)
            .WithMany(c => c.Responses)
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.PostId);
modelBuilder.Entity<ResponseReply>()
            .ToTable("ResponseReply")
            .HasRequired(c => c.ParentResponse)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.ParentResponseId);
```

This will create 3 tables for you just to handle the Response idea in your model.
This helps you enforce the fact that PostId and ParentResponseId are actually required and it will create **`"NOT NULL"`** columns in the separate tables.

If you do not want separate tables and leave your foreign keys as optional in the database, just remove the **`ToTable()`** call from your modelBuilder block.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Arturo - I'm dealing with almost the same exact problem here, and I tried your suggestion.  If you have a moment, any advice here would be much appreciated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168808/ef-codefirst-why-is-this-fk-not-getting-added-via-modelbuilder

Comment: @SB2055 - I can't seem to find your question in stackoverflow.com. Did you delete the question?

Comment: Oh man, I'm sorry. I figured it out, it was a dumb user error :p.   I appreciate the follow-up.

Answer (score 0):

You could inherit `Reponse` from `Post` and have only *one* foreign key, so you'll never have to worry about which FK should be set:

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post ParentPost { get; set; }
    public int? ParentPostId { get; set; }
}

public class Response : Post
{
}
```

With the mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasOptional(p => p.ParentPost)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.ParentPostId);
```

Now if you do

```
var a = new Post();
var b = new Response { ParentPost = a };
var c = new Response { ParentPost = b };
db.Posts.Add(c);
db.SaveChanges();
```

you'll get

```
PostId      ParentPostId Discriminator
----------- ------------ -------------
1           NULL         Post
2           1            Response
3           2            Response
```

Maybe this doesn't work if posts and responses are essentially different things, but I can hardly imagine that's the case.

Comment: Gert - thanks for the suggestion.  I was trying to keep Posts and Responses as separate entities Posts have a ton of properties that Responses will never have, but they do share some properties.  If I told you that performance was more important than convenience, what would you recommend?

Comment: Then go for separate classes. All inheritance schemes have more or less overhead. I think you can only rely on business logic to set the right FK value. A rigorous safeguard could be to make both FKs different types (e.g. a guid for posts).

Comment: Ok, got it.  Is there any way to use modelbuilder to set nullable FK constraints on both?  I can't figure out the syntax for that, or even if it's needed if I take the separate classes approach.